# ¿Cómo llamar a métodos asincrónicamente desde una acción?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Desde un método de acción quiero llamar a diversos métodos que realizan determinadas acciones y que tardan algo de tiempo en ejecutarse.
Para que sea más rápido, y como estas acciones son individuales quiero llamarlas de manera que se ejecuten en paralelo, y una vez que hayan terminado, hacer otras cosas.
Un ejemplo sería algo así:

```
public ActionResult MiAccion(MiViewModel m)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Realizar tarea 1
        var t1 = Tarea1(m);
        //Realizar tarea 2
        var t2 = Tarea2(m);

        //Cuando las tareas 1 y 2 hayan terminado
        var result = t1+t2;
        ... ("Otras cosas")
    }
    ...
}

private int Tarea1(MiViewModel m)
{
    ...
    //LLamamos a un servicio que tarda un rato y devuelve un int
    return LlamadaServicio();
}
private int Tarea2(MiViewModel m)
{
    ...
    //LLamamos a un servicio que tarda un rato y devuelve un int
    return LlamadaServicio();
}
```

¿Cómo debería declarar los métodos y realizar las llamadas?

Comment: Hola Carlos, echa un vistazo a https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lanzar tareas deberias evaluar el uso de `Task` entonces lanzas la ejecucion en diferentes `thread` (hilos).

[Programación asincrónica basada en tareas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)

quizas algo como esto

```
Task<int>[] taskArray = { Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => Tarea1(m)),
                             Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => Tarea2(m))};  



Task.WaitAll(taskArray);   

var results = new int[taskArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) 
{
    results[i] = taskArray[i].Result;

}
```

Comment: Lanzar tareas no es sinónimo de asincronía, puedes lanzar tareas en mas de un hilo y aun así trabar la interfaz (las tareas se están ejecutando en paralelo, pero no significa que dejen libre al hilo principal.

Answer (score 1):

No hay que confundir paralelismo con asincronía, son dos cosas distintas. El paralelismo no es siempre la opción a implementar pues no siempre la tarea es afín a ser paralelizada.

Si la tarea incluye acceso IO (por ejemplo acceso a base de datos) generalmente no se puede paralizar bien, en esos casos sería mejor procesos asíncronos.

Un ejemplo utilizando métodos asíncronos:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MiAccion(MiViewModel m)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Realizar tarea 1
        var t1 = await Tarea1(m);
        //Realizar tarea 2
        var t2 = await Tarea2(m);

        //Cuando las tareas 1 y 2 hayan terminado
        var result = t1+t2;
        //... ("Otras cosas")
    }
    ...
}

private Task<int> Tarea1(MiViewModel m)
{
    ...
    //LLamamos a un servicio que tarda un rato y devuelve un int
    return Task.Run(() => LlamadaServicio());
}
private Task<int> Tarea2(MiViewModel m)
{
    ...
    //LLamamos a un servicio que tarda un rato y devuelve un int
    return Task.Run(LlamadaServicio());
}
```

Esto no significa que Tarea1 y Tarea2 se ejecuten en paralelo, significa que, mientras se ejecutan, el servidor puede serguir recibiendo peticiones y la ejecución de MiAccion no "traba" todo hasta que terminen Tarea1 y Tarea2.